# Floor values in raster stack cell to certain quantile of cell values r

Tags: r, stack, raster

I'm struggling with flooring cell values of a raster stack. Here some example data:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
s <- stack(lapply(1:365, function(i) setValues(r, runif(100, 0, 1))))
# adding NAs
s[[2]][sample(100, 25, TRUE)] <- NA
s[sample(100, 25, TRUE)] <- NA
```

I have got a raster stack with time series for an entire year. Some cells are completely set to NA as well as some single values within time series. 
I'm trying to floor the values in each cell to the lower .025 quantile of the cell. This is how far I got with my function:

```
f <- function(i) {
  v_q <- quantile(i,probs = .025 ,na.rm=TRUE)
  if (length(v_q) > 0) {
    if(i[v_q] < v_q) {
      i[v_q] <- v_q
    }
    i
  }
  i  
}

x <- calc(s, fun = f)
```

When I apply it to `calc` I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the error, but your function looks a bit odd.

First, let's add a random seed for reproducibility:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(42)
s <- stack(lapply(1:365, function(i) setValues(r, runif(100, 0, 1))))
# adding NAs
s[[2]][sample(100, 25, TRUE)] <- NA
s[sample(100, 25, TRUE)] <- NA
```

`calc` on a stack or brick basically works with vectors of values across the layers.

So this should work:

```
f <- function(i) {
  q <- quantile(i,probs = .025 ,na.rm=TRUE)

  i[i<q] <- q
  i

}

x <- calc(s,fun=f)
```

And to test:

```
q <- calc(s,fun = function(x) quantile(x,0.025,na.rm=T))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(s[[1]] < q,main="s[[1]] < q")
plot(x[[1]] == q,main="x[[1]] == q")
```

[image]